# How to create a email link in POI Word Format

Tags: java, apache-poi

How can I create an external link or an email link in a [XWPFDocument](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html)? There is a description for [Excel (HSSF XSSF)](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Hyperlinks), but i haven't found anything similar for Word (HWPF XWPF).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public void example() throws Exception{

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(); 
        //Append a link to 
        appendExternalHyperlink("https://poi.apache.org", " Link to POI", document.createParagraph());

        document.write(new FileOutputStream("resultat.docx"));
    }

    /**
     * Appends an external hyperlink to the paragraph.
     * 
     * @param url The URL to the external target
     * @param text The linked text
     * @param paragraph the paragraph the link will be appended to.
     */
    public static void appendExternalHyperlink(String url, String text, XWPFParagraph paragraph){

        //Add the link as External relationship
        String id=paragraph.getDocument().getPackagePart().addExternalRelationship(url, XWPFRelation.HYPERLINK.getRelation()).getId();

        //Append the link and bind it to the relationship
        CTHyperlink cLink=paragraph.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();
        cLink.setId(id);

        //Create the linked text
        CTText ctText=CTText.Factory.newInstance();
        ctText.setStringValue(text);
        CTR ctr=CTR.Factory.newInstance();
        ctr.setTArray(new CTText[]{ctText});

        //Insert the linked text into the link
        cLink.setRArray(new CTR[]{ctr});
    }
```

Comment: This was really helpful! So the hyperlink appears now but the anchor text doesnt appear in blue text or with the underline. Can you tell me which method I should be using to create styles in CTR class? There is no documentation and hence its hard to figure out which method does what.

Comment: After some strong googling, this is what I found. Sorry about the formatting. CTRPr rpr = ctr.addNewRPr(); CTColor colour = CTColor.Factory.newInstance(); colour.setVal("0000FF"); rpr.setColor(colour); CTRPr rpr1 = ctr.addNewRPr(); rpr1.addNewU().setVal(STUnderline.SINGLE);

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, XWPF has support for reading and manipulating hyperlinks, see [XWPFHyperLinkRun](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFHyperlinkRun.java) and [XWPFHyperlink](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFHyperlink.java) for details.

There's not currently any user facing code to handle creating hyperlinks in XWPF, but all the components are there (handling of the low level hyperlink objects, ability to add hyperlinks into the relations etc). A patch to tie this together to provide the missing functionality would be very much appreciated by all!

Comment: @Gagravarr can you please help me out for the [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612420/how-to-work-around-poi-xwpf-hyperlink)

Answer (score 4):

All,

The above example shows how to create an external hyperlink. For those who need to create an internal hyperlink, see below code:

```
XWPFParagraph hyperPara = document.createParagraph();
hyperPara.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
addHyperlink(hyperPara, "Hyperlink Text", "Heading Text");



private static void addHyperlink(XWPFParagraph para, String text, String bookmark) {
     //Create hyperlink in paragraph
     CTHyperlink cLink=para.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();
     cLink.setAnchor(bookmark);
     //Create the linked text
     CTText ctText=CTText.Factory.newInstance();
     ctText.setStringValue(text);
     CTR ctr=CTR.Factory.newInstance();
     ctr.setTArray(new CTText[]{ctText});

     //Create the formatting
     CTFonts fonts = CTFonts.Factory.newInstance();
     fonts.setAscii("Calibri Light" );
     CTRPr rpr = ctr.addNewRPr();
     CTColor colour = CTColor.Factory.newInstance();
     colour.setVal("0000FF");
     rpr.setColor(colour);
     CTRPr rpr1 = ctr.addNewRPr();
     rpr1.addNewU().setVal(STUnderline.SINGLE);

     //Insert the linked text into the link
     cLink.setRArray(new CTR[]{ctr});
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add this internal hyperlink to a XWPFTableCell?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that Apache POI isn't near as far in the handling of Word files than it is in handling Excel documents. If you are in the early stage of development maybe you could consider moving to [Docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/projects.html).

Cheers,
Wim