# How to add a hyperlink to the footer of a XWPFDocument using Apache POI?

Tags: java, hyperlink, apache-poi, footer, xwpf

The `appendExternalHyperlink()` method [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007810/how-to-create-a-email-link-in-poi-word-format) is not working in the footer of a XWPFDocument. In the footer the result is not getting recognised as a hyperlink.

I am new to Apache POI and have no experiences with the low level stuff. Can someone explain what is the problem in here, please?

```
public class FooterProblem {

  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    final XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();
    final XWPFParagraph para = docx.createParagraph();
    final XWPFRun paraRun = para.createRun();
    paraRun.setText("Email: ");
    appendExternalHyperlink("mailto:me@example.com", "me@example.com", para);

    final XWPFParagraph footer = docx.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT).createParagraph();
    final XWPFRun footerRun = footer.createRun();
    footerRun.setText("Email: ");
    appendExternalHyperlink("mailto:me@example.com", "me@example.com", footer);

    final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("FooterProblem.docx");
    docx.write(out);
    out.close();
    docx.close();
  }

  public static void appendExternalHyperlink(final String url, final String text, final XWPFParagraph paragraph) {

    // Add the link as External relationship
    final String id = paragraph.getDocument().getPackagePart()
        .addExternalRelationship(url, XWPFRelation.HYPERLINK.getRelation()).getId();

    // Append the link and bind it to the relationship
    final CTHyperlink cLink = paragraph.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();
    cLink.setId(id);

    // Create the linked text
    final CTText ctText = CTText.Factory.newInstance();
    ctText.setStringValue(text);
    final CTR ctr = CTR.Factory.newInstance();
    ctr.setTArray(new CTText[] { ctText });

    // Insert the linked text into the link
    cLink.setRArray(new CTR[] { ctr });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `footer[n].xml` is its own package part and needs its own relations. But your code creates the external hyperlink relations for the `document.xml` package part always. It always uses `paragraph.getDocument()`. This is wrong.

The following code provides a method for creating a `XWPFHyperlinkRun` in a given `XWPFParagraph` and gets the correct package part to put the relations on. It uses `paragraph.getPart()` to get the correct part. So this method works for paragraphs in the document body as well as in header and/or footer.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHyperlink;

public class CreateWordHyperlinks {

 static XWPFHyperlinkRun createHyperlinkRun(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String uri) throws Exception {
  String rId = paragraph.getPart().getPackagePart().addExternalRelationship(
    uri, 
    XWPFRelation.HYPERLINK.getRelation()
   ).getId();

  CTHyperlink cthyperLink=paragraph.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();
  cthyperLink.setId(rId);
  cthyperLink.addNewR();

  return new XWPFHyperlinkRun(
    cthyperLink,
    cthyperLink.getRArray(0),
    paragraph
   );
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("This is a text paragraph having a link to Google ");

  XWPFHyperlinkRun hyperlinkrun = createHyperlinkRun(paragraph, "https://www.google.de");
  hyperlinkrun.setText("https://www.google.de");
  hyperlinkrun.setColor("0000FF");
  hyperlinkrun.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE);

  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText(" in it.");

  XWPFFooter footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
  paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Email: ");

  hyperlinkrun = createHyperlinkRun(paragraph, "mailto:me@example.com");
  hyperlinkrun.setText("me@example.com");
  hyperlinkrun.setColor("0000FF");
  hyperlinkrun.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordHyperlinks.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for replying immediately. If I want to learn more about Apache POI—XWPF in particular—what is a good starting point for understanding the low-level code?

Comment: @Martin: Download [ooxml-schemas](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.4) source and do `javadoc` from it. The `ooxml-schemas` are classes generated from `Office Open XML` specifications. So the classes correspond to the `XML` elements you get if  you unzip the `*.docx` file and have a look into the `/word/document.xml` or `/word/footer1.xml`.

Comment: These hints are very useful to me! Thanks a lot.