# XWPFDocument - External hyperlink creation - path shows as "localpath+url" I only need it written as "url"

Tags: java, apache-poi

I needed to append an external url in a word document with Apache POI. I found and used the following code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22456273/7896122

However, there the link is unopenable on some machines, and I suppose it is because it is written in the format: `[local path of the file]/[url]`, while I only need it like `[url]`.

This is happening somewhere within this method, but I don't have that advanced knowledge of Apache POI, to understand what exactly I need to change:

```java
private static void appendExternalHyperlink(String url, String text, XWPFParagraph paragraph) { 

   // Add the link as External relationship
    String id = paragraph.getDocument().getPackagePart()
            .addExternalRelationship(url, XWPFRelation.HYPERLINK.getRelation()).getId();

    // Append the link and bind it to the relationship
    CTHyperlink cLink = paragraph.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();
    cLink.setId(id);

    // Create the linked text
    CTText ctText = CTText.Factory.newInstance();
    ctText.setStringValue(text);
    CTR ctr = CTR.Factory.newInstance();
    ctr.setTArray(new CTText[] { ctText });

    // Insert the linked text into the link
    cLink.setRArray(new CTR[] { ctr });
}
```

Comment: This depends on the `String url` given in your code. If that is a relative `URI` then that URI is relative to the Word document file. If that is not wanted a complete `URI` (`file://...`) must be given.

Comment: it is a plain url ([https://.....]). 
The problem is, that, if I add a hyperlink from within Word, it is added normally in the given format - [url]. However, when I do it with the code snippet above, I end up with [local path of the file]/[url], which I believe causes my problem. Any suggestions?